# Remove Content-Length Header in Guzzle Multipart Request

Tags: php, guzzle

When sending a multipart request with Guzzle 6 a Content-Length header is appending to each field that's sent in the form.

For example:

```
$this->client->post($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'USERAGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'CSIDivision',
            'contents' => '09 Finishes'
        ]
    ]
])
```

Shows up like so on the receiving end:

```
--706c9415168df0a5df108e43017c846201b960ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CSIDivision"
Content-Length: 11

09 Finishes
```

The receiving end of this exchange is another company I'm working with and they are having difficulty parsing around this `Content-Length` text and I want to know how to get rid of this.

They built their API using Postman which doesn't include this field, it only seem to show up in Guzzle.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: "_They are having difficulty parsing around this Content-Length text_" In other words: they're having difficulty parsing a totally normal header that's there in 99% of the cases. You don't need to "fix" this, THEY need to get their <bleep> together. Most likely they're doing some homegrown response parsing. Try explaining that the `Content-Length` is part of a normal HTTP response and that it's up to them to handle it.

Comment: @RobIII that's exactly what I told them, but that doesn't seem to satisfy my client on this piece. Setting the header `Content-Length` to null seems to work. Thanks mate.

Comment: Tell your vendor "git gud, scrublord".

Comment: "_Setting the header Content-Length to null seems to work_" I hope this client is the only client using that part of your code because, if not, you just took away any chance for all other clients to display a progressbar or any other means of progression indication.

Comment: ...though, thinking about it, you _could_ get away with it by adding a checkbox to accounts indicating if they need the `Content-Length` header.  Or maybe even by sniffing the useragent (hoping they use a unique useragent) and then determining if you want to send the `Content-Length` header. Whatever way, though, this is a dirty hack for a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: This is a backend process implemented by a background queue job. No user interaction is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a legacy application/webserver and solved with this CURL option:

```
'curl' => [
   CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
],
```

Your request will become like this:

```
$this->client->post($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'USERAGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'CSIDivision',
            'contents' => '09 Finishes'
        ]
    ],
    'curl' => [
        CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
    ],
])
```

Before:

User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/7 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=571b6f82a4b19533cb0fafaf3f3d6753aa3f64e8 
Content-Length: 316

After:

Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/7 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;  boundary=311c35ea25c9e091fa01c39353541ec99ef16e62